# Determine if div appears between two separate div's

Tags: jquery, html

Been searching high and low and can't seem to find an answer to this one. I've got a page full of small square divs and am trying to come up with a method to check and see if a div falls in between two other divs on the page. For example:

Two div's normal:

[A]---------[B]

Page changes and loads a third div:

[A]---[C]---[B]

Assuming div's are 10px high, what would be the easiest way to determine if C fell at any point in between A and B?

Hopefully I explained it well enough, thanks for the hand!!

Edit to add more detail, don't think I explained it well enough. I'm looking to find if the middle div is between A and B using the 'physical' locations on the page.

Say div A's top/left offset is 0,10 and div B is at 0,100. Each div is 10px tall so I'm trying to figure the simplest way to determine that div C falls in between them if it's top/left is at say 9,50. Hope that's a bit clearer.

Comment: How are the divs positioned on the page?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this HTML:

```
<body>
  <div class="someClass"></div>
  <div class="someOtherClass"></div>
  <div class="aClass"></div>
  <div class="alsoaClass"></div>
</body>
```

Now, jQuery's `index` will tell you what position that DIV is in:

```
$('.someClass').index(); // 0
$('.someOtherClass').index(); // 1
$('.aClass').index(); // 2
$('.alsoaClass').index(); // 3
```

Like this, you can always compare their positions in DOM.

---

If what you're trying to do is get the position relative to the window (not according to their DOM positions), then you should check their `offset`:

```
$('.someClass').offset().top; // will give you amount of pixels from the top of the document
```

Comment: Offset plus size might do it. Then you have to write collision detection code. OP, why do you want to do this again??

Answer (score 1):

On the assumption that the divs share a common parent and are displayed in DOM order:

The .index() property is probably what you are after

Documentation: http://api.jquery.com/index/

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Y7aWM/4/

```
function between(before, current, after)
{
    var $current = $(current);
    var $before = $current.parent().children(before);
    var $after = $current.parent().children(after);

    var before_index = $before.index();
    var current_index = $current.index();
    var after_index = $after.index();

    return (before_index < current_index && current_index  < after_index );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I cannot vouch for the reliability, but the DOM clientTop property might be of some interest.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.clientTop

Answer (score 0):

```
function checkPosition(divID)
{

  if($('#'+divID).next().attr('nodeName') == 'DIV' && $('#'+divID).prev().attr('nodeName')=='DIV')
    alert('its between two divs');
}
```

I hope this helps